# Azure Cloud Block Blob, preventing a process overwriting the changes made by a different process

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

My use case scenario of Azure cloud block blob is like following:

**1.** There is a blob called **phone-numbers.txt** in azure storage container

**2.** Machine A downloads the blob, makes some changes, then upload it to the container with the same blob name.

**3.** Machine B may do the same thing as machine A, but with different changes.

Machine A and B could download the blob at the exactly same time, but machine A may be faster completing and uploading the change to container.

The issue happens when machine B uploads its change without knowing that machine A has made a change to the blob. Of course, I can have each machine do `Append` only, but if the changes made by both machines are same, I need to keep only one instead of appending the same change twice.

So I was wondering if Azure store has any existing mechanism to prevent this overwrite happening. If Azure does not have it, I was thinking about using the metadata in the blob and having a version field in the metadata:

When a machine updates the blob, it increments the version by +1. Before the machine uploads the blob, it downloads the same blob and check whether its version has changed from its first download. I know this is not perfect and the blob download seems redundant.

Any other better approaches to prevent the overwriting from happening?

Comment: IMHO, accepted answer will not work in your scenario. I have provided an answer. Please take a look at my answer for another solution.

Comment: that makes more sense, the top priority is to prevent one process overwriting the changes made by another process. Blob lease will not work right for my purpose. thanks

Comment: This basically boils down to a choice between optimistic concurrency (using `ETag`) and pessimistic concurrency (using blog leasing). Both achieve the behaviour you're after, but the choice depends on things like the update frequency, the cost of each update attempt, etc. so will be application specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO blob leasing is not the right solution to this problem. Let me explain.

Let's assume both process A and B downloads the blob to work on it and A is able to acquire the lease on the blob. Now consider these scenarios:

- **B has finished the job before A**: Even if B has finished the job before A, B can't save the blob as A has exclusive lock on the blob. B will need to wait for A to release the lock before B can save the changes.
- **A has finished the job before B**: In this scenario the lock will be released hence B will be able to save the changes but it will have no idea that A has made the changes thus A's changes will be overwritten with B's changes.

To solve this issue, you will need to use something called **Optimistic Concurrency** which is supported by default in Azure Storage. This is accomplished by making use of of `ETag` property of a blob which gets updated anytime a blob is changed.

So considering the same example as above, both A and B downloaded the blob and start working on editing it.

- **B has finished the job before A**: In this case, B will be able to save the changes. As soon as B saves the changes, ETag of the blob will be changed and now when A try to save the changes an error (`419 - Precondition Failed`) will be thrown by storage service which will tell A that the blob has changed. A will need to download the blob again and make the changes and save again.
- **A has finished the job before B**: Same thing will happen as above but now B will get the same error and B will need to re-download the blob and make the changes and save again.

You can learn more about concurrency in Blob Storage here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-concurrency#managing-concurrency-in-blob-storage

Comment: The assumption about the leasing approach is not quite right. Both the download and the update happen within the duration of the lease, so each process is guaranteed to be working with the latest changes. Process B will not be able to acquire a lease if Process A already has one, and therefore will not download the blob until Process A has finished updating it and released the lease.

Comment: Your comment about leasing is incorrect. You can certainly read from (in a sense download) a leased blob. You’ll not be able to update or delete a leased blob though.

Comment: It's certainly true that a leased blob can be downloaded by a process that does not hold the lease, but this should not happen if the process always acquires a lease (for itself) before downloading the blob. I've added some explanation to my answer below to hopefully clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Microsoft docs for [Leasing Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob). This effectively allows you to request a lease/lock on the blob before you update, which will prevent other processes from updating (or deleting) that blob for the duration of the lease. So each process can do something like the following to prevent concurrent updates to the same blob:

1. **Attempt to acquire lease for blob** - This will fail if a lease has already been acquired by another process. You can specify a timeout for this attempt so that it does not fail immediately and gives the other process a chance to finish updating the blob. Once this lease has been acquired, no updates to the blob can be made by other processes until it is released.
2. **Download blob** - Since an exclusive lease has been acquired by this process during step (1), the downloaded blob is guaranteed to contain the most recent changes.
3. **Make changes to contents**
4. **Overwrite old blob by uploading new contents** - Since an exclusive lease has been acquired by this process during step (1), the blob being overwritten is guaranteed to just be the same blob that was downloaded in step (2) because the lease protects against updates from other processes for its duration.
5. **Release lease** - Frees up the blob to be updated by other processes.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to compare metadata of the 2 files.

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=metadata
```

Alternatively consider a multi-writer scenario with append blobs where each machine can append a block to an existing blob.